# NGINX - Domain can't get to the correct server blocks

Tags: configuration, nginx, hosting, virtualhost

I'm trying to host multiple websites using Nginx in a single server with single IP only.

This is what I did:

I created a domain name ninjoequah.uni.me , uni.me is a free domain.

I enter my public IP in the target URL of the domain only. Thats the only configure I done in the domain. I got my public IP from [WhatIsMyIP](http://www.whatismyip.com/)

I have 2 server blocks in

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

configuration for www (default)

```
server {
    listen: 80;
    server_name localhost;

   root /usr/share/nginx/www/localhost
   ...

}
```

Its the default configuration only.

Configuration for ninjoequah.uni.me

```
server {
    listen: 80;
    server_name *.ninjoequah.uni.me ninjoequah.uni.me;

   root /usr/share/nginx/www/ninjoequah.uni.me
   ...

}
```

Anything else are the same as well.

I tried to connect locally by configure my hosts file. I add the following line

```
127.0.0.1 ninjoequah.uni.me
```

It works! I even tried to connect locally with other PC.

```
192.168.0.105 ninjoequah.uni.me
```

It works too. Everything seems to be fine.

But when I tried to connect using my domain. Both www.ninjoequah.uni.me and ninjoequah.uni.me cant get me to the correct block.

They will be taken to the www block which is the default server.

Did I miss out anything or I configure wrongly?

Please help thanks

**UPDATE**

I checked the access log. Reading the log, I found out that the HOST will always be my IP address.
The domain name will only be the referrer.

And sometimes you can't even see the domain name as a referrer. The referrer will be '-' or my IP too.

Is this the DNS problem?

Comment: can you provide the detail info of your server block how you implemented it? its hard to guess like this and confusing to read.

Comment: i had provided my block details

Comment: Have you tried running the command: sudo service nginx restart